# Combine "connection" and "transit" tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-synonyms

The [connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection) and [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit) tags cover largely the same ground, 
and to me they seem to be used more or less interchangeably.

**Should we combine them** (make one a synonym of the other)?

(If you think they should **not** be combined, could you give a "for dummies" explanation of when each tag should be used? I'd like to improve the tag wikis at least.)

Currently, the tag wiki descriptions are:

[connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection)

> Questions about connecting flights or other forms of transport.

[transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit)

> Passing through a place briefly while travelling on the way to
>   somewhere else.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but in my opinion, the word transit refers mainly to air travel while connection has a much broader meaning.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that (looking at the current tag wiki, or a dictionary, "transit" doesn't refer especially to air travel). By the way, almost all questions tagged with *either* tag are about air travel.

Comment: I thought "transit" meant an international connection, but I haven't looked at how the tags are actually used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend making [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit) main tag and [connection](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection) a synonym.

Comment: I'm not sure which should be primary. Combine them by all means but after reading choster's answer maybe a new tag name might be best?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the game, but must voice a strong concern with the proposal.

"Transit" in American English almost invariably refers to public transportation. It's in the names of major agencies such as [New Jersey Transit](http://www.njtransit.com/) and the [San Diego Metropolitan Transit System](http://www.sdmts.com/), and for that matter [Google Transit](http://www.google.com/transit). Merriam-Webster gives the last part of the primary definition of "transit" as

> local transportation especially of people by public conveyance;

While questions heretofore may have been about air travel, as this site gains momentum I can easily see someone asking "Can I get from LAX to Olvera Street by transit?" or "What are my transit options on Christmas in Atlanta?" and tagging the question in the same way.

Anecdotally, I would say the terminology "transit passenger" is significantly less common than "connecting passenger" outside of those in the travel industry, not surprising because the overwhelming majority of flights are domestic, unlike most of the world, and I think most concerns about being in transit relate to customs and immigration questions.

So, I would certainly not consider *transit* to be a synonym of *connection*, and would see if it can be "salted" to force someone to choose between *connection* and *public transport*.

Comment: Hmm for this sense of "transit" we already have another tag that works in all English rather than just US English: [tag:public-transport].

Comment: The existence of alternative terms doesn't change the fact that *transit* is still ambiguous. Besides, an American would say *public transportation*.

Answer (score 0):

**Done as @Ankur suggested..**

Comment: This should be a comment and accept of Ankur's answer rather than a separate answer.

Comment: @hippietrail Can't accept his answer :)

Comment: Oh yeah didn't realize you were the "solver" but not the OP `(-:` Still shouldn't be an answer though d-: