# Should Questions tagged 'short-connections' routinely be tagged with 'transit' also?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I think the nature of [Transferring at Zürich Airport do I need to go through Passport Control or only Security?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57639/transferring-at-z%c3%bcrich-airport-do-i-need-to-go-through-passport-control-or-only) is clear from the Title (I wrote it).

Initially tagged by OP with [air-travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/air-travel) I edited to, amongst other things, replace that tag with:

[customs-and-immigration](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/customs-and-immigration) [short-connections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connections) [zrh](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zrh)

I did not add tag [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit) on the basis that transit is an inherent aspect of short connections (and others).

Another user has added [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit).

Is the addition appropriate?

---

There are 112 Open posts tagged [short-connections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connections) at present, of which 38 are also tagged [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit).

Related: [Combine “connection” and “transit” tags?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/810/combine-connection-and-transit-tags)

Related [Do 'transit' and 'layover' mean the same thing?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/do-transit-and-layover-mean-the-same-thing)

Usage guide for [short-connections](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-connections) (as last edited by me) is currently:

> Where connections, typically between flights, leave little margin (such as close to Minimum Connection Times between terminals).

Usage guide for [transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transit) is currently:

> Passing through a place briefly while travelling on the way to somewhere else.

The former has no synonyms, the latter has 'connection'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, only one tag should be usually sufficient, for the same reason why questions about Berlin should avoid doing all 5 possible tags: [berlin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/berlin), [germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany), [central-europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-europe), [europe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe), [eu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu). It would also make it easier to find questions which focus exclusively on one aspect or the other in the future.